# $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f| < \infty$. Then $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) =0\;?$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If $\int_0^\infty fdx$ exists, does $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197450/if-int-0-infty-fdx-exists-does-lim-x-to-inftyfx-0)

Let $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f| < \infty$. Then $$  \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) =0 \;?$$
If this is true, then how can I prove this?

Comment: Basically the same question as this one: [If $\int_0^\infty fdx$ exists, does $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197450/if-int-0-infty-fdx-exists-does-lim-x-to-inftyfx-0)

Comment: Consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if }x \in \mathbb{Q} \\0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ for a counterexample.

Comment: @Marvis Thank you for your comment. But how about the case of $f \in L^1(\Bbb R)$ ?

Comment: @Ann $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{n} \chi_{[n,n+4^{-n}]}$.

Comment: Marvis's function *is* in $L^1$!

Comment: If you let $f$ be uniformly continuous,then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
n,&\text{if }n\le x\le n+\frac1{n^3}\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb Z^+\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;;
\end{cases}$$

then $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{n}{n^3}=\frac{\pi^2}6\;,$$

but $\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. You can replace the steps with ‘tents’ to make $f$ continuous without qualitatively affecting the example; you can even round off the corners to make it arbitrarily differentiable.

Comment: An easy way to make it $C^\infty$ is to use the same idea, but scale Gaussian functions instead.

Comment: E.g. $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty e^{-4^k(x-k)^2}$?

Comment: Noting that $\liminf\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ shows that the limit does not exist. However, if the limit exists...