# Does this integral converge or diverge ? $\int_\Bbb R \left (\frac{2+\cos x}{3}\right )^{x^4}dx?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I would like to prove that the function

$$f(x) = \left (\frac{2+\cos x}{3}\right )^{x^4}$$
is Lebesgue-integrable on $\mathbb R. $
 Namely I would like to show that,

$$\int_{\Bbb R} \left|f(x)\right|dx<\infty$$

My answer:
\begin{split}\int_{\Bbb R}\left|f(x)\right|dx&=&2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+2)\pi}\left (\frac{2+\cos (x)}{3}\right )^{x^4}\,dx\\
&=&2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\left (\frac{2+\cos (x+2n\pi)}{3}\right )^{(x+2n\pi)^4}\,dx\\
&\leq& 
2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\left (\frac{2+\cos (x)}{3}\right )^{(2n\pi)^4}\,dx<\infty?.
\end{split}

Comment: @Masacroso I mean absolute value

Comment: I deleted my answer because the infinite integral converges, and i could have a proof for Riemman integrability, but not for Lebesgue integrability.

Comment: just an idea: you can write the integral as the sum of two series using the fact that the cosine is periodic. Or maybe exists some change of variable that make the limits of integration finite.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Note that $0<\frac{1}{3}\leq \frac{2+\cos x}{3}\leq 1$ and 
\begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|f(x)\right|dx&=
2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\left (\frac{2+\cos (t+2k\pi)}{3}\right )^{(t+2k\pi)^4}\,dt\\
&\leq 
4\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi}\left (\frac{2+\cos (t)}{3}\right )^{(2k\pi)^4}\,dt.
\end{align*}

Comment: This is Riemman integrability actually.....

Comment: @hyprfrcb you are right... the Lebesgue integrability is not as simple in all cases, however it seems that it coincides in this case. This was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214482/is-there-a-general-theory-of-the-improper-lebesgue-integral)

Comment: hello, i am not able to figure out why the last term series converge

Comment: @Guy Fsone You can use the inequality given by Jack D'Aurizio in his anwer.

Comment: Yes but the problem is I dont get how he got his inequality too. this function is nice for me but keep putting me into troubles

Answer (score 5):

**Lemma**. For any $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ we have $\frac{2+\cos x}{3}\leq e^{-x^2/9}$.

It follows that:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2+\cos x}{3}\right)^{x^4}\,dx &\leq&\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^6/9}\,dx+2\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{9}(x+2n\pi)^4\right]\,dx\\&\leq& \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}{3^{2/3}}+2\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left[-\frac{16n^4 \pi^4}{9}x^2\right]\,dx\\&=&\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}{3^{2/3}}+\frac{3}{4\pi^{3/2}}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}\\&=&\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}{3^{2/3}}+\frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{8}\end{eqnarray*}$$
so $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2+\cos x}{3}\right)^{x^4}\,dx\leq \color{blue}{7}.$

Comment: Hello, @Jack please how do you prove your Lemma?

Comment: @GuyFsone: it is enough to consider a Padé approximant of $\log\frac{2+\cos\sqrt{x}}{3}$ on the interval $[0,\pi^2]$. But you do not really need such sharp bound, $\frac{2+\cos x}{3}\leq e^{-x^2/18}$ is simpler to prove and works just as well for proving the convergence of the given integral; even $\frac{2+\cos x}{3}\leq e^{-x^2/1000}$ does the job.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{split}\int_{\Bbb R}\left|f(x)\right|dx&=&2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+2)\pi}\left (\frac{2+\cos (x)}{3}\right )^{x^4}\,dx\\
&=&2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\left (\frac{2+\cos (x+2n\pi)}{3}\right )^{(x+2n\pi)^4}\,dx\\
&\leq& 
2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\left (\frac{2+\cos (x)}{3}\right )^{(2n\pi)^4}\,dx<\infty.
\end{split}

> Let us justify this: $$ \frac13 \le  \left (\frac{2+\cos x}{3}\right )^{x^4}\le 1 $$
>   implies  $$\left (\frac{2+\cos (x)}{3}\right )^{(x+2n\pi)^4} \le\left (\frac{2+\cos (x)}{3}\right )^{(2n\pi)^4}~~x\in(0,2\pi) $$ on the other hand,
>   $a(x) = \ln\left(\frac{2+\cos (x)}{3}\right )< 0
> ~~a.e$ then, $$ \lim_{n\to \infty }n^4 \left(\frac{2+\cos (x)}{3}\right )^{(2n\pi)^4}= \lim_{n\to \infty }n^4\exp\left(a(x)(2n\pi)^4 \right) =0$$ hence, for $n$ large enough we have 
>   $$\int_0^{2\pi}\left (\frac{2+\cos x}{3}\right )^{(2n\pi)^4}\,dx \le \frac{C}{n^{4}}$$ this entails that
>   \begin{split}\int_{\Bbb R}\left|f(x)\right|dx&\le & 
> 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\left (\frac{2+\cos (x)}{3}\right )^{(2n\pi)^4}\,dx\\
> &\le& C\sum_{n =0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}
> \end{split}